# Asp.net Identity 2.0 custom login method

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-identity-2

I'm developing ASP.NET 5 application using Identity 2.0. I have two types of users:

1. Normal - they authenticate using standard login method.
2. Temporary - they should login based on provided token.

I do not want to store temporary users, except from information required to authenticate user (some username and token). If the user provides username and valid password he should be logged in.

I'm not sure how to achieve this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use Identity in both scenarios simultaneously as well. For first scenario use Identity just like you have done before without any change but for second scenario you a slight modify in login method.

```
public ActionResoult TempLogin(string username, string password)
{
    // imaging you have own temp user manager, completely independent from identity
    if(_tempUserManager.IsValid(username,password))         
    {
        // user is valid, going to authenticate user for my App
        var ident = new ClaimsIdentity(
        new[] 
        {
            // adding following 2 claim just for supporting default antiforgery provider
            new Claim(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier, username),
            new Claim("http://schemas.microsoft.com/accesscontrolservice/2010/07/claims/identityprovider", "ASP.NET Identity", "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string"),

            // an optional claim you could omit this 
            new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, username),

            // you could even add some role
            new Claim(ClaimTypes.Role, "TempUser"),
            new Claim(ClaimTypes.Role, "AnotherRole"),
            // and so on
        },
        DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie);

        // Identity is sign in user based on claim don't matter 
        // how you generated it Identity 
        HttpContext.GetOwinContext().Authentication.SignIn(
            new AuthenticationProperties { IsPersistent = false }, ident);

        // auth is succeed, 
        return RedirectToAction("MyAction"); 
     }
     ModelState.AddModelError("", "We could not authorize you :(");
     return View();
}
```

Since we injected our logic to Identity, we don't need to do extra thing at all.

```
[Authorize]
public ActionResult MySecretAction()
{
    // all authorized users could use this method don't matter how has been authenticated
    // we have access current user principal by calling also
    // HttpContext.User
}

[Authorize(Roles="TempUser")]
public ActionResult MySecretAction()
{
    // just temp users have accesses to this method
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I was investigating this on my own and came to similar solution. Alternativly one could use SignInAsync method of SignInManager passing "fake" User object. This would result in centralized place to create Claims for both normal and temporary users in CreateUserPrincipalAsync, although one would need to distinguish both type of users in this method.

Comment: @Sam using your method if a user with unauthorised role tries to access the page he gets browser error page saying too many redirects.. It doesn't redirect to login page like default identity does. How to show custom error "Not authorised" for such users?

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to extend the ASP.NET Identity Libraries, using your custom logic and/or storage.

Here you can find an example in my Github account with some useful links that I used to read when I was trying to understand the ASP.NET Identity stuff: https://github.com/hernandgr/AspNetIdentityDemo

Hope it helps!