# How to check if a user is authenticated in MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I have done custom authentication system by following this [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31584506/how-to-implement-custom-authentication-in-asp-net-mvc-5) and it works. my code is like below. I am wondering how I should control if the user is authenticated in other Actions, lets say if users goes to /Profile/Index?

I have tried HttpContext.User and User.Identity but didnt work.

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Login(string username, string password)
{
    if (new UserManager().IsValid(username, password))
    {
        var ident = new ClaimsIdentity(
          new[] {
      new Claim(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier, username),
      new Claim("http://schemas.microsoft.com/accesscontrolservice/2010/07/claims/identityprovider", "ASP.NET Identity", "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string"),
      new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name,username)
          },
          DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie);

        HttpContext.GetOwinContext().Authentication.SignIn(
           new AuthenticationProperties { IsPersistent = false }, ident);
        return RedirectToAction("MyAction"); // auth succeed 
    }
    ModelState.AddModelError("", "invalid username or password");
    return View();
}
```

this is my Global.asax

```
protected void Application_Start()
{
    AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
    FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
    RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
    BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);
}
```

Comment: What does User.Identity.IsAuthenticated returns after logging in and moving to /Profile/Index?

Comment: Have you tried `HttpContext.GetOwinContext().Authentication.User.Identity.IsAuthenticted`?

Comment: @DavidG, it returns false

Comment: @AliBaig, User.Identity.IsAuthenticated also returns false

Comment: And on Profile controller, it passes through the [Authorize] attribute but returns false on IsAuthenticated?

Comment: it gives this error HTTP Error 401.0 - Unauthorized

Comment: do you have anything about  "FormsAuthentication" in your web.config?

Comment: I just checked it, FormsAuthentication is not in web.config

Comment: Have you got anything in your `IdentityConfig.cs`, hopefully `UseCookieAuthentication`?

Comment: I dont have IdentityConfig.cs file. should I have one?

Comment: How about anything to do with auth config, it needs to be called from `Global.asax.cs/Application_Start`?

Comment: I added my Global.asax above. nothing about auth config

Comment: OK, let me add an answer

Comment: thank you very much @DavidG

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not setting up authentication in your Owin pipeline. The easiest way is to add a file like the one below. Call it `IdentityConfig.cs` and put it in the `App_Start` folder:

```
using Microsoft.AspNet.Identity;
using Microsoft.Owin;
using Microsoft.Owin.Security.Cookies;
using Owin;

//This line tells Owin which method to call
[assembly: OwinStartup(typeof(TokenBasedAuthenticationSample.IdentityConfig))]
namespace TokenBasedAuthenticationSample
{
    public class IdentityConfig
    {
        public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
        {
            //Here we add cookie authentication middleware to the pipeline 
            app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
            {
                AuthenticationType = DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie,
                LoginPath = new PathString("/Account/login"),
            });
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: it cannot find UseCookieAuthentication

Comment: Did you add the `using` statements as above? Do you have the `Microsoft.Owin.Security.Cookies` package installed?

Comment: I added it, but when it goes to MyAction, claim seems empty

Comment: Does the action have the `Authorize` attribute?

Comment: no I dont, but I just added it. now, it goes to default login page.

Comment: is there a sample project online, I messed up a bit

Comment: You can try this https://github.com/samfgl/TokenBasedAuthenticationSample